# Raise os.walk when file not found

Tags: python

I want the the script to stop running if a "key" was not found in a file.
If my directory looks like this:

```
Dir
   ->file.xml
   ->file2.xml
   ->yyy.m
   ->ignoreTXT.txt
   ->ignoreC.c
   ->ignoreANYTHING.anything
   ->Dir2 -> file3.xml, xxx.m, yyy.m
```

Lets say i have two keys in my json file: `"Hello"` and `"World"`
If the key `"Hello"` was found in `file2.xml` and `xxx.m` it should print it out and continue with the next key. If `"World"` was not found it should give an `Exception`.

The first issue is that my script looks through other files (such as `.txt`, `.c` etc). I want to ignore them but I don't want to use `os.remove` since it will remove the files and I need them. Are there any other alternative? Because due to this my "raise Exception" will give error since `"Hello"` was not found in `.txt` file (which I dont care about).

The second issue is that even though `"Hello"` was found it will give me an error since it could not find anything in `file.xml` or `file3.xml`, `ignoreTXT.txt`, `ignoreC.txt` etc.

```
jdata = json.load(open(json_path))
path = findAllFiles(directory)

if os.path.isdir(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for key, value in jdata.iteritems():
            for name in files:
                with open(os.path.join(root, name)) as fle:
                    content = fle.read()
                if name.endswith('.txt') and re.search(Wordboundry(key), content):
                    print "Name", key, "was found in", name, "\n"
                    writeToFile(value, content, name, key)
               else:
                   print "Name", key, "was not found in", name
    else:
        raise Exception(key, "was not found in", root) #This gives me error even though "Hello" can be found in file2.xml. 



def FindName(content, key, name, value):
    if name.endswith('.xml') and re.search(Wordboundry(key), content):
        print "Name", key, "was found in", name, "\n"
        OverrideXML(key, value, name)
    elifif name.endswith('.m') and re.search(Wordboundry(key), content):
        print "Name", key, "was found in", name, "\n"
        OverrideM(key, value, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily filter out non .xml files as follows:

```
if os.path.isdir(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

        xmlFiles = [file for file in files if file.endswith(".xml")]

        for key, value in jdata.iteritems():
            for name in xmlFiles:
                ...
```

This creates a sublist of `files` which only contains those names ending in the xml file extension. You can then loop through this sublist for your search

Answer (score 0):

You put your `else` in the wrong indentation. This will work:

```
if os.path.isdir(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for key, value in jdata.iteritems():
            for name in files:
                if not name.endswith('.txt'):
                    continue
                with open(os.path.join(root, name)) as fle:
                    content = fle.read()
                if re.search(Wordboundry(key), content):
                    print "Name", key, "was found in", name, "\n"
                    writeToFile(value, content, name, key)
                else:
                    print "Name", key, "was not found in", name
                    raise Exception(key, "was not found in", root)
```

Comment: `Why should I do re.search(Wordbounry(key), content)` again when I already do that part?

Comment: @gants you don't... You do it only once.

Comment: The issue is still there though. It will still look into the other .xml files even though it already has found the "key" in another file. As long as it finds the "key" in one file it should give error. Sorry if I am a bit unclear